# Video Streaming of iOS Simulator screen - buffering issue

Tags: ios, macos, video-streaming, ios-simulator

**My Goal**

I am trying to create a live streaming video of an iOS simulator screan (for live demonstrations).

**In Theory**

According to `xcrun simctl io help`:

> *Usage: simctl io < device > < operation > < arguments >*
>
> *Supported operations:*
>
> > recordVideo [--type=< type >] [--display=< display >] < file >
> >
> > > Records the main framebuffer display to the specified file (use "-" for stdout).
>
> *Example:*
>
> > **Pipe fragmented mp4 video of the booted device to another program:**
> > simctl io booted recordVideo --type=fmp4 - | < other program >

**In Practice**

When I run: `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo --type=fmp4 -` on a booted simulator, there's some ~700KB buffer that would only flush once in a few seconds (depending on the screen modifications).

**My Question**

Is there any way to make the piped buffer smaller, or read the simulator's frame buffer directly, not via `simctl`?

***UPDATE:***
Apple fixed this bug sometime in the beta versions of Xcode 8.3 (thanks @russbishop!)

Comment: This appears to be a bug; it was intended to be a continuous stream. Can you file a bug at https://bugreporter.apple.com? You can include a link to this post in the report.

Comment: Thanks @russbishop, I will.

Comment: radar #29846218

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look

Comment: This should work better in the Xcode 8.3 beta releases.

Comment: You are right, in the terminal it seems to work now as expected. I also received a notice from apple that "The original report on your issue has been closed recently" (apperantly it was a duplicate...). Need to test if this allows streaming to video player applications (such as VLC) and then I'll be able to start developing my stream server!

Comment: @Elist did you ever manage to get this to work? I'm currently trying to use the streaming feature but unable to make it work

Comment: @Elist are you still able to use this ? I am getting the following error
`error: rendering to standard out is no longer supported` . Using xcode version 11.3.1